# Calling virtual function from a class destructor in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, destructor

The question of calling virtual functions inside constructor or destructor has been discussed in many other questions and resources, but I would like to clear something about it, that I still feel missing.

For example, in Scott Meyers, Effective C++, Item 9 there's a full explanation. But the ending comment is

> Don't call virtual functions during construction or destruction, because such calls will never go to a more derived class than that of the currently executing constructor or destructor

So what I'm trying to understand in what sense calling virtual function from constructor or destructor unsafe.

- Is it unsafe in the sense that I could get unexpected runtime behavior, because the virtual table status is "non deterministic" in the destructor?
- Or, is it unsafe in the sense that it is something that is not maintainable because I'm likely to get a different behavior then I expect?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it unsafe in the sense that I could get unexpected runtime behavior, because the virtual table status is "non deterministic" in the destructor?

The C++ standard doesn't discuss a vtable implementation. It discusses behavior. And the behavior is that the call is resolved (as if) statically.

As far as the implementation, those typically "revert" the vptr so it points at the vtable of the classes *currently* being destructed, early in the execution of the destructor.

> Or, is it unsafe in the sense that it is something that is not maintainable because I'm likely to get a different behavior then I expect?

Depends on what you expect. If you *know* how the call is resolved, you'll get what you expected

```
class Thing {
public:
    virtual ~Thing() { frombulate(); }
    void frombulate() const { do_frombulation(); }
private:
    virtual void do_frombulation() const = 0;
};

inline void Thing::do_frombulation() const {}
```

Like I said, you may be aware of what behavior to expect, so even though `do_frombulation` is pure virtual, you provided an implementation.

If are aren't aware, you may have omitted the empty definition. In which case, your program will exhibit undefined behavior (likely crashing, since that entry in `Thing` 's vtable won't be populate by a valid address) and you may be surprised by it. A compiler may inform you if you call an unimplemented pure virtual `do_frombulation` *directly* in a constructor/destructor body, but it can't check *all* execution paths.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it unsafe in the sense that I could get unexpected runtime behavior ...

Unexpected behaviour is exactly the sense in which it is unsafe. A reader or author of the program is likely to expect that calling a virtual function invokes the most derived override. This assumption is not true in detructor (nor in constructor) which may be unexpected.

> ... because the virtual table status is "non deterministic" in the destructor?

There is nothing "non deterministic" about the behaviour.

> Or, is it unsafe in the sense that it is something that is not maintainable because I'm likely to get a different behavior then I expect?

Unexpected behaviour is typically different from behaviour that one expects. So, yes.